# Select text of li elements through JQuery

Tags: javascript, java, jquery, user-interface

How can I select the text from list elements through `JQuery`. I want the same functionality as that of  `.select()` in `javascript`, but  that is only applicable to editable text areas/input boxes, can someone guide me ,for the same functionality with list elements

I want the list text to be selected on `.click()`.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/MarkSchultheiss/aSvst/23/ - I want something like this for list elements

Comment: Your jsFiddle has no `li` elements... ?

Comment: @Pebbles your question is not clear, please provide some code snippet

Comment: @Rory the jsfiddle just shown the functionality of selecting text onclick, which i seek in my code. the .select() works for textarea/editable input boxes

Answer (score 1):

Try this: http://jsfiddle.net/bigneo/w0y5yrcr/1/

**HTML**

```
<ul id="ulmonth">
    <li>Jan</li>
    <li>Feb</li>
    <li>Mar</li>
    <li>Apr</li>
    <li>May</li>
    <li>Jun</li>
    <li>Jul</li>
    <li>Aug</li>
    <li>Sep</li>
    <li>Oct</li>
    <li>Nov</li>
    <li>Dec</li>    
</ul>
```

**JS**

```
$.fn.OneClickSelect = function(){
    return $(this).on('click',function(){
    var range, selection;
    if (window.getSelection) {
            selection = window.getSelection();        
            range = document.createRange();
            range.selectNode(this);
            selection.removeAllRanges();
            selection.addRange(range);
     } 
     else if (document.body.createTextRange) {
            range = document.body.createTextRange();
            range.moveToElementText(this);
            range.select();
     }
    });
};

// Apply to these elements
$('li, #all-select').OneClickSelect();
```

I think I found your answer in this post:
https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/38089/select-text-with-just-one-click

Comment: Yes buddy, this is exactly the functionality i want, i am trying to alter for 'li' elements..if i am able to then i shall post it here...until then i am open to anybody make this happen for list elements.

Comment: I have edited my answer. Check out new jsfiddle link. What I changed is `range.selectNodeContents(this);` to `range.selectNode(this);`

Answer (score 0):

http://jsfiddle.net/zfk9s8zq/

**HTML**

```
<ul id="ulmonth">
    <li>Jan</li>
    <li>Feb</li>
    <li>Mar</li>
    <li>Apr</li>
    <li>May</li>
    <li>Jun</li>
    <li>Jul</li>
    <li>Aug</li>
    <li>Sep</li>
    <li>Oct</li>
    <li>Nov</li>
    <li>Dec</li>    
</ul>    
<label id="lblTest"></label>
```

**JQUERY**

```
$(function(){
    $("#ulmonth li").css("cursor","pointer");
    $("#ulmonth li").click(function(){
        var txt = $(this).text()
        $("#lblTest").text(txt);
    })
})
```

Comment: thank you, i appreciate your answer, but i want the whole text to be selected....like the demo jsfiddle i have put.....say..in ur jsfiddle example..i click on May...then May should be selected as a whole as text

Comment: I am sorry, I didn't get you. If you click on `may` in my solution, then you will the text `May` gets selected and is shown at the bottom. Please clarify.

Comment: Please check the jsfiddle example I have posted above for a better understanding. I hope you will get an idea...by looking into that.

Comment: Sorry I am unable to understand your JSFiddle. Please help me understandit

Comment: pls check the jsfiddle of bigneo, that's what i want ...for List elements in an Unordered List

Comment: oh .. sorry. i wasn't of much help

Comment: NO...not at all @Rajan, any input is much appreciated, thanks for your time

Comment: I was confused at the start also and I was unsure what was the question. Because questions states: Select text of li elements through JQuery. You are talking about 3 things here. Text, li and JQuery. If it's not text as Rajan answered then I figured it must be li itself.